# Is there an automatic way to fit lines in document with multiple columns?

Tags: multicol, grid-typesetting

I've noted that professional multicolumn documents usually manage to fit the parallel lines. With that I mean that all the lines of both columns are perfectly at the same height. This is achieved by making the paragraph title spaces + title height a multiple of an ordinary line height.

I've seen that this isn't the case for my document. Now, I could calculate and adjust all the section and subsection heights and spaces which would be a lot of work.

Therefore I wanted to ask if there is a LaTeX package that automatically makes sure that lines of two columns are always perfectly at the same height!

Thanks in advance and best regards

Comment: It's actually quite tricky in TeX, but the grid-typesetting tag link I added will give you some pointers

Comment: Is it tricky to the point where you would recommend not going for such a design for a PhD thesis document design? The document would include a large number of within-column figures. So, spaces before and after these figures should be adjusted such that text of both column is always perfectly at the same height.

Nature (the scientific journal) manages to do this, for example.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a 2-col thesis:-) Up to you, try some of the packages and if they work they work, and if they don't, just use a normal tex setting, the impact on the document markup should be small so not something you need to decide in advance

Comment: the reason why it is tricky is most of tex's layout model is based on its "boxes and glue" paradigm and you can't allow any vertical white space to stretch as that will break the grid alignment, it's easy enough to set space around floats and lists etc to fixed amounts but that makes page breaking harder so it takes more manual control. Nature probably uses something like in-design where everything is visual and manually controlled, but fitting manual control into a batch oriented typesetter like latex is challenging.

Comment: In fairness I should probably mention that reports are that context is better at this than latex at the present time (tighter interaction with the lua back end of luatex)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insights! Well, if it's tricky to establish 2-col thesis format with little effort, which it seems to be, it will probably be best to just go with what everybody else does and stay with the 1-col format. I think it should be possible to make a 1-col format look beautiful as well.

Comment: Depending on where you are, you may find that 'beautiful thesis' is contradictory. But, then, you wouldn't be considering 2-column in those places, I assume.

Comment: What do you mean? :P

Comment: What does who mean by what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the commenters have noted a fully automated TeX solution is not yet available. As noted the `grid` package is a step on the way. A *Glisterings* article in *TUGboat* gives a couple of other partial solutions. One is concerned with paragraphs that have to be set in a different sized font than normal and the other where different font sizes are used in the same paragraph.
You can find the article here https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-3/tb111glister.pdf and see sections **5 Line backing** and **6 Linespacing**.